# Woes of implementing selection sort in x86 NASM or YASM Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm, yasm

I am attempting to implement a selection sort of an array in NASM that runs on 64-bit Linux.

The array is declared as:

```
section .bss
strbuf resb 10
small  resb  1  ; current minimum value
```

The sort algorithm itself is quite simple, but I feel limited by two things: the number of registers available, and the inability to swap immediates (i.e. brackets)

I need to keep track of the unsorted array boundary, its index, the location of the current smallest value, and its index. That's four registers already. I also need to keep track of two loop counters, one for the outer loop that represents the unsorted array boundary, and one for the iteration on each pass (i.e. inner loop). That's another two, totalling six registers.

As immediates cannot be moved to each other such as `mov [var1], [var2]` I need to use a register as a temporary placeholder whenever I need to swap two elements. This quickly grows unwieldy in terms of tracking which registers hold what information!

Below is my attempt so far. Please note that this is **non-working code** that triggers a segmentation fault. But maybe you can perceive what I am trying to do and point out where my approach is going wrong.

I do not wish to use macros that simplify constructs, such as those that provide .IF and .ELSE.

```
; ====== Sorting begins here ======
sorting:
    mov edi, strbuf  ; outer loop pointer
    mov esi, strbuf  ; inner loop pointer
    mov eax, 0  ; inner loop counter
    mov ebx, 0  ; outer loop counter

innerloop:
    ; store the value of first element in [small]
    mov edx, [esi]
    mov [small], edx

    ; compare the current small value with the value pointed by esi
    mov edx, [esi]  
    cmp [small], edx

    jg  new_small
    inc esi
    inc eax
    cmp eax, 9
    jle innerloop
    cmp eax, 9
    jg  innerloop_done

new_small:
    mov [small], edx  ; save the new small value
    mov ecx, esi      ; save its index in ecx
    inc esi
    inc eax
    cmp eax, 9

    jle     innerloop

innerloop_done:
    ; When the inner loop is completed...
    ; First, do the swap
    push    rax
    mov eax, [edi]
    mov edx, [small]
    mov [ecx], edx
    pop rax

    inc edi  ; move the outer loop pointer forward
    inc esi  ; move the inner loop pointer forward
    inc ebx  ; increment the outer loop counter (the unsorted array becomes smaller)
    inc eax  ; increment the inner loop counter (same reason as above)
    cmp ebx, 9

    jle innerloop   

; ====== Sorting ends here ======
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be many guides on how to properly structure assembly code. Whenever you read a programming book for popular languages such as C++, C or Java, you always come away with grounded, solid programming principles to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. In assembly, the only principle seems to be "Shoot yourself in the foot as often as you need to make your program work."

Comment: :)) ASM is very attention-demanding and requires a lot of meticulous and tedious work. But! It's better than C and C++ in one respect. It's fixed. x86 bytes, words and dwords don't change in size when you use a different assembler. And x86 ASM isn't directly applicable to or recompilable for other platforms like ARM or MIPS. There isn't undefined behavior stemming from the language standard which C/C++ programmers rarely read and understand. The CPU manual says precisely what's valid for this CPU and what's not. WYSIWYG! :)

Comment: You can use a number of high-level programming techniques in ASM too. You can define subroutines, you can define macros, all that to not repeat yourself and to avoid some bugs. You can comment the code. You can structure it in multiple modules. You can have callbacks and other indirectly-callable subroutines. Virtual methods, if you wish. In ASM you can do everything, it's just quite a bit more code and work.

Comment: Thanks. I have also found that very few high-level programming concepts will help in assembly. My mind is wired to think of a datum as either a value, pointer, or address. But in ASM, it seems none of those concepts apply since a register doesn't know what type of data it contains.

Comment: ASM is extremely explicit and low-level in nature. There are no hidden function calls, jumps, stack unwinding, type conversions, temporary objects. What I've found is that knowing ASM helps a lot with learning C and C++. The other way around, not so much. And that's for a reason. C and C++ grew up and out from ASM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 64-bit code there are 16 general purpose registers: RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RSI, RDI, RSP, RBP, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15.

Of these, RSP has a special purpose and can only be used for that purpose (current stack address). The RBP register is typically used by compilers for keeping track of the stack frame (excluding "-fomit-frame-pointer" possibilities), but you aren't a compiler and can use it for anything you like.

This means that out of 15 registers that you could be using, you're only using 6 of them.

If you actually did run out of registers, then you could shift some things to stack space. For example:

```
foo:
    sub rsp,8*5        ;Create space for 5 values
%define .first   rsp
%define .second  rsp+8
%define .third   rsp+8*2
%define .fourth  rsp+8*3
%define .fifth   rsp+8*4
%define .first   rsp+8*5

    mov [.first],rax
    mov [.second],rax
    mov rax,[.first]
    add rax,[.second] 
    mov [.third],rax
...
    add rsp,8*5        ;Clean up stack
    ret
```

Hopefully you can see that you could have hundreds of values on the stack, and use a few registers for (temporarily) holding those values if you need to. Normally you'd work out which values are used most often (e.g. in the inner loop) and try to use registers for them and use the stack for the least frequently used variables. However, for 64-bit code (where there are 8 more registers you can use) it's very rare to run out of registers, and if you do it's probably a sign that you need to split the routine into multiple routines.

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I wasn't aware of the registers r8-r15. They weren't mentioned in class or in any of the learning material. From what I've found, they didn't seem to exist in 32-bit x86. 

When you clean the stack using `add esp, 8*5` does that completely invalidate all the previous register assignments? How does moving `esp` affect things? What if I moved the stack pointer backwards using `sub esp, 8*5` instead?

Comment: @Terribad: You really need to start reading Intel/AMD CPU documentation. It will tell you how many registers there are, what instructions are available and precisely what they do.

Comment: @Terribad: Changing the stack pointer has one simple but very important effect besides getting a different value in (e/r)sp. All on-stack data at addresses less than (e/r)sp is practically invalid because it can be overwritten by the activities of interrupt service routines, signal handlers and the like because they too, unsurprisingly, need to use the stack. If you increment rsp by too much and then restore it, you can lose the return address, which is stored on the stack. And, of course, on-stack parameters and local variables are subject to the same.

Answer (score 2):

If this is supposed to execute in 64-bit mode, you have to use 64-bit addresses, which means when you take those addresses and place them into registers, those recipient registers must be 64-bit as well, otherwise you'll truncate the addresses and access memory not quite where you intend.

Also, don't you have a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: Is there a good assembly debugger for Linux besides gdb? gdb doesn't seem to work with assembly code very well.

Comment: I guess I've been using 32-bit registers because that's what the book examples use. Since the program deals with chars only, I use 8-bit registers later on in the program as well. I was under the impression that 8-bit registers such as AL should be used when processing characters?

Comment: If you process characters one at a time, 8-bit registers/variables are perfect. If you want to process several at once, you need bigger registers/variables. As for gdb, I'm not on Linux, but it must be possible to debug ASM programs with it as well. See if you need to enable debug/symbolic information in NASM or the linker (if there's any involved) using a command-line parameter. That may help somewhat. Otherwise, even with small programs like the above, it shouldn't be such a big deal to look at the disassembly instead of seeing the source code and having all variable/subroutine names.